# Dependence On Initial Conditions and Parameters.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

[image]

I'm having a hard time getting started with this problem.  I'm not even sure if this can be done by computing some derivatives or what not or if I need to use a proof for this solution.

Comment: can you write down the solution of the ODE $x'=Ax, x(0) = x_0$?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of linear system tells us that the solution to the IVP is x(t) = e^(At)x0.  In this case our initial condition at time = 0 is y so would the solution be x(t) = e^(At)*y ?

Comment: Correct. Now patch these solutions together to a function
$$u: \mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n, \quad (t,y) \mapsto u(t,y)=x(t)|_{x_0=y}$$
and you're good to go.

Comment: So u(t,y) = e^(At)*y, then Phi(t,y) is the partial derivative of of u(t,y) with respect to t.  This gives us Phi(t,y) = Ay*e^(At)?

Comment: By the way, Thank you very much AlexR for taking the time to help me with this.  This class uses a lot of analysis to prove the theorems we're using, yet I haven't taken it yet.

Comment: Be aware of the dimensions used. $Ay\exp(tA)$ is invalid (maxtrix-vector-matrix doesn't work); but essentially, that's correct.